# Python inheritance from parent class in a module form different folder

Tags: python, class, parent

I have the following directory

```
  - actions
    - create_session.py
    - lib
      - __init__.py
      - prep_vars.py
      - details.xlsx
```

I have the following code in prep_vars.py

```
class PrepVars(object):

    def __init__(self):

        try:
            self._wb = load_workbook(filename='details.xlsx', data_only=True)
            self._ws = self._wb['Switch Details']
        except IOError:
           print ("test 123")
        self.ipadd_sw1 = self._ws['C7'].value
        self.ipadd_sw2 = self._ws['D7'].value
        self.user_sw1 = self._ws['C8'].value
        self.user_sw2 = self._ws['D8'].value
        self.password_sw1 = self._ws['C9'].value
        self.password_sw2 = self._ws['D9'].value
        self.icl1_sw1 = self._ws['C10'].value
        self.icl1_sw2 = self._ws['D10'].value
        self.session_vlan = self._ws['C12'].value
        self.session_network = self._ws['C13'].value
        self.session_subnet = self._ws['C14'].value
```

and the below code in create_session.py

```
from lib.prep_vars import PrepVars

class SessionRun(PrepVars):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PrepVars, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print ("test {0}".format(self.ipadd_sw2))
```

I am getting an error (see below) when I run the code. I am not sure why this is happening. if I have the code running inside prep_vars.py it runs normally.

the error

```
AttributeError: 'SessionRun' object has no attribute '_ws'
```

Comment: `super(PrepVars, self).__init__()` should be `super(SessionRun, self).__init__()`. As is you are not calling `PrepVars.__init__()` but `object.__init__()` skipping over `PrepVars`.

Comment: I tired that. received a different error then I discovered that the Sheet should be in the actions folder not in lib folder. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could be your `try` block raised an exception. Did you see `"test 123"` printed out? If so, that confirms the exception raise, so `._ws` was not defined.

It's not the best idea to use `try...except` this way.